# JSF1064: Ressource not found! only when i use my Project in Firefox

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, wildfly-18

Im using Java, Wildfly18, Primefaces and JSF in my Project but im getting this Warning!
anyone know why im getting this Warning when i use the Project only in Firefox?
Any information would be helpful.
here is the Server log :

> WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application]
> (default task-290) JSF1064: Ressource core.js aus Bibliothek
> primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden. 17:13:41,237
> WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application]
> (default task-290) : java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException     at
> io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.write(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:238)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.write(HttpServerExchange.java:2105)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeBufferBlocking(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:574)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:150)
> at
> java.base/java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(Channels.java:464)
> at
> com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP04//com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:318)
> at
> javax.faces.api@3.0.0.Final//javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:171)
> at
> deployment.ZeitverwaltungEAR.ear//org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:97)
> at
> javax.faces.api@3.0.0.Final//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:704)
> at
> javax.faces.api@3.0.0.Final//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
> at
> io.opentracing.contrib.opentracing-jaxrs2//io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
> at
> org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> at
> org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> at
> org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
> at
> org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
> at
> org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
> at
> org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
> at
> org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
> at
> org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
> at
> org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
>
> 17:13:41,238 WARNING
> [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default
> task-291) JSF1064: Ressource components.js aus Bibliothek primefaces
> kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden. 17:13:41,249 WARNING
> [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default
> task-291) : java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException  at
> io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.write(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:238)

Comment: I googled around, and I see this warning experienced by many. One suggestion I found is to suppress the warning: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?p=178484#p178484 

Lots of posts are 2018 or earlier, so maybe you just need to update something (Primefaces, Firefox).

Comment: Thanks, but i already found the solution. in the Standalone.xml we should disable the enable-http2="true" in the next line:
                <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="false"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found the solution. in the Standalone.xml we should disable the http2 in the next line:

> 

Answer (score 0):

Only disable server push:
`/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https:write-attribute(name=http2-enable-push,value=false)`